# Достать координаты из строки

Tags: c++

Нужно сделать программу достающую координаты вида (x,y) из строки, вроде как написал, но почему то достается только одна точка, первая, не понимаю в чем ошибка.

```
void main() {
string pointstr;
Point pointn;
vector<Point> points;

cout << "Enter coords: ";
cin >> pointstr;

size_t start = pointstr.find('(');
size_t comma = pointstr.find(',');
size_t end = pointstr.find(')');

while (start != string::npos && comma != string::npos && end != string::npos) {
    pointn.x = stod(pointstr.substr(pointstr.find("(") + 1, pointstr.find(",") - 1));
    pointn.y = stod(pointstr.substr(pointstr.find(",") + 1, pointstr.find(")") - 1));
    pointstr.erase(pointstr.find("("), pointstr.find(")") + 1);
    points.push_back(pointn);
    start = pointstr.find('(');
    comma = pointstr.find(',');
    end = pointstr.find(')');
}



for (vector<Point>::iterator it = points.begin(); it < points.end(); it++) {
    cout << it->x << " " << it->y << endl;
}

system("pause");
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У нас же с++? так давайте писать на с++!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// это структура для точки
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

// определим оператор ввода с потока
// собственно, это основная часть вопроса
// в коде делаем небольшие проверки, что у нас все в порядке
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Point & p)
{
    char c;
    is >> c;
    if (c != '(') {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    is >> p.x;
    is >> c;
    if (c != ',') {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    is >> p.y;
    is >> c;
    if (c != ')') {
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    return is;
}

// ну как же без оператора вывода!
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    os << '(' << p.x << ", " << p.y << ')';
    return os;
}

// пример использования
int main()
{
    std::stringstream s{"(1,2) (2,3)"};
    Point p;
    std::vector<Point> points;
    while (s >> p) {
        points.push_back(p);
    }

    for (auto& p:points) {
        std::cout << p << "\n";
    }
}
```

Но теперь можно писать даже так

```
Point p;
std::cin >> p;
std::cout << p;
```

и все будет работать "Из коробки". Точно также можно даже в файл выводить

Comment: Я хотел узнать в чем моя ошибка, если на то пошло, ваш код хорош, но я не понимаю будет ли он работать с числами с плавающей точкой, да и тем более мне необходимо достать координаты именно из готовой строки.

Comment: нужны вещественные - поменяйте в Point типы - будет работать. Как читать с строки - я показал в примере. Но может Вам не нужно читать с строки, а прямо читать сразу